# como receber dados dinamicamente via websocket?

Tags: javascript, html5, websocket

estou tentando atualizar uma `<div>` da qual está recendo dados do banco de maneira dinâmica, porém, tentei implementar desta maneira e mesmo assim continua errado e não sei onde tô errando, vou deixar o código fonte logo abaixo separados por arquivos.

arquivo principal (app.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const porta = process.env.PORT || 3000
const Usuario = require('./models/Usuario');
const admin = require('./routes/admin')


//configurando segurança do app
app.use(helmet());
//session
//configurar aqui!
//template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
//socket.io
var gettingDados = Usuario.findAll({ limit: 1, order: [['id', 'desc']] })


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log(`usuarios ${socket.id} conectado!`)
    io.emit('data_getting', gettingDados)
    socket.on('data_getting', function(msg){
        let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++
        io.emit('data_getting', gettingDados)
        console.log('mensagem recebida', msg)
    })

})
//rotas
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index')
})


app.use
app.use('/admin', admin)

http.listen(porta, () => {
    console.log(`servidor rodando na url http://localhost:${porta}`);
})
```

página de registro(registro.ejs):

```
<% for( let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++ ) { %>
<div id="relatorio">
    <small id="id">id: <strong><%- usuarios[i].id %></strong></small><br>
    <small id="nome">Nome: <strong><%- usuarios[i].nome %></strong></small><br>
    <small id="email">Email: <strong><%- usuarios[i].email %></strong></small><br>
    <small id="senha">Senha: <strong><%- usuarios[i].senha %></strong></small><br>
</div>
<hr><% } %>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('listen', )

    socket.on('data_getting', function(msg){
        document.getElementById('relatorio').innerHTML = msg
    });
</script>
```

e por fim a rota que manda as consultas no banco para essa página

```
registro(router/admin.js):
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Usuario = require('../models/Usuario')

router.get('/cadastro', (req, res) => {
    res.render('admin/cadastro')
})

router.post('/cadastro', (req, res) => {
    Usuario.create({
        nome: req.body.nome,
        email: req.body.email,
        senha: req.body.senha
    }).then(() => {
        res.send('usuário cadastrado com sucesso!')
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send('não foi possível cadastrar novo usuário' + err)
    })
})

router.get('/registro', (req, res) => {
    Usuario.findAll({ limit: 1, order: [['id', 'desc']] }).then((usuarios) => {
        res.render('admin/registro', {usuarios:usuarios})
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

o resultado que aparece é o seguinte:
[image: resultado do websocket]

Comment: O que vc pretende que seja feito quando um cadastro for realizado? É para chamar alguma função? Para atualizar alguma parte da página?

Comment: Isso mesmo quero que só o elemento pai atualize e mostre o resultado sem ser a página inteira a cada novo registto

Comment: Sendo esse o caso, adicione a parte do HTML que deverá ser atualizado e o que vc espera que apareça no caso de um evento.

Comment: Entendi a teoria o problema é a implementação eu estou implementando errado, é que eu sou novo na programação então em algumas coisas me enrolo, teria como vc me mostrar um exemplo prático amigo? Baseado nessa mesma condição que citei?

Comment: Para isso é necessário vc adicionar o seu HTML e o que pretende fazer. Existe inúmeras formas de se criar notificações, caso seja o que vc pretende fazer. Caso seja simplesmente atualizar a página, é preciso conhecê-la.

Comment: Quando me refiro a "atualizar a página" estou me referindo a uma parte da pagina, como um div.

Comment: Entendi amigo de qualquer forma vou tentar implementar depois mando o resultado aqui msm assim obrigado pela ajuda vc me deu uma idéia que pode funcionar, pelo menos em teoria

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil, não esqueça de dar o vote up e marcar como aceita.

Comment: Lembre de sempre incluir na pergunta todas as informações e adicionar todo o código relacionado, para que as pessoas saibam o que foi tentado e apontem onde pode mudar.

Comment: Com as edições é possível ver que vc não entendeu como e quando usar websockets. Vou editar a resposta para incluir mais partes do seu código e tentar explicar os problemas...

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta?

Comment: Desculpa amigo ter demorado tanto pra responder, na verdade quem tá vendo essa parte do código é outro rapaz só coloquei aqui o que eu tentei fazer e nem tinha visto sua resposta pois estamos tentando fazer um projeto e vou ver com ele e assim que puder posto aqui

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo apresentado, diria que a dúvida é mesmo como "começar". O melhor caminho seria olhar a documentação do Socket.IO e tentar aplicar o "getting started" para o seu projeto. Entretanto, o que foi apresentado não é um bom exemplo para demonstrar o uso do Socket.IO, já que é somente um cadastro de usuários.

Como inicializar o backend

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Quando for necessário enviar um evento para o frontend:

```js
io.emit('NOME_DO_EVENTO', "mensagem...");
```

para atualizar o frontend

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('NOME_DO_EVENTO', function(msg){
          // AÇÕES NO FRONTEND
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**EDITADO:** o trecho abaixo foi adicionado para usar o código apresentado na pergunta.
Alterações a serem feitas:

- Não é necessário lançar eventos ao carregar a página, portanto, parte do código 
  foi comentado em app.js
- Lança evento ao cadastrar um usuário
- Apanha o evento no frontend e atualiza a div relatorio (observe que ainda são necessárias outras correções no HTML, que estão fora do escopo da pergunta)

app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const porta = process.env.PORT || 3000
const Usuario = require('./models/Usuario');
const admin = require('./routes/admin')


//configurando segurança do app
app.use(helmet());
//session
//configurar aqui!
//template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

//socket.io
// código abaixo não é necessário
//var gettingDados = Usuario.findAll({ limit: 1, order: [['id', 'desc']] })

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
// código abaixo não é necessário
//    console.log(`usuarios ${socket.id} conectado!`)
//    io.emit('data_getting', gettingDados)
//    socket.on('data_getting', function(msg){
//        let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++
//        io.emit('data_getting', gettingDados)
//        console.log('mensagem recebida', msg)
//    })
})

//rotas
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index')
})


app.use
app.use('/admin', admin)

http.listen(porta, () => {
    console.log(`servidor rodando na url http://localhost:${porta}`);
})
```

Cadastro

```js
registro(router/admin.js):
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Usuario = require('../models/Usuario')

router.get('/cadastro', (req, res) => {
    res.render('admin/cadastro')
})

router.post('/cadastro', (req, res) => {
    Usuario.create({
        nome: req.body.nome,
        email: req.body.email,
        senha: req.body.senha
    }).then(() => {
        io.emit('new_user', {nome: req.body.nome, email: req.body.email})
        res.send('usuário cadastrado com sucesso!')
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send('não foi possível cadastrar novo usuário' + err)
    })
})

router.get('/registro', (req, res) => {
    Usuario.findAll({ limit: 1, order: [['id', 'desc']] }).then((usuarios) => {
        res.render('admin/registro', {usuarios:usuarios})
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

registro.ejs:

```js
<% for( let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++ ) { %>
<div id="relatorio">
    <small id="id">id: <strong><%- usuarios[i].id %></strong></small><br>
    <small id="nome">Nome: <strong><%- usuarios[i].nome %></strong></small><br>
    <small id="email">Email: <strong><%- usuarios[i].email %></strong></small><br>
    <small id="senha">Senha: <strong><%- usuarios[i].senha %></strong></small><br>
</div>
<hr><% } %>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('new_user', function(msg){
    // AÇÕES NO FRONTEND
    // AQUI DEVERIA SER FEITO ALGO PARA ADICIONAR O NOVO USUÁRIO À LISTA DE USUÁRIOS
    // ENTRETANTO, O SEU HTML NÃO ESTÁ FEITO CORRETAMENTE
    // POR ISSO, O CÓDIGO ABAIXO SUBSTITUIRÁ AS INFORMAÇÕES DA DIV relatorio
    document.getElementById('relatorio').innerHTML = "Usuário " + msg.nome + " adicionado."
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Eu posso não ter sido muito claro na minha pergunta mas vamos lá, o que na verdade eu quero é monitorar essa rota de registros toda vez que tiver um usuário novo ela mostrar na tela sem atualizar a página inteira eu só consigo implementar em Webchat fora disso eu não consegui, gostaria de uma maneira

Comment: Então melhore sua pergunta, seja mais objetivo. Ta muito grande e achei que a resposta estaria correta para sua pergunta .